# delete button is creating dynamic event in selenium...delete is not like a button.its like an icon in my site..how to solve this?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium for automating my site.my site is an administrative site that add roles and delete them as well,there is an add button at the top to add the roles, but delete button is present in all the roles and hence this creates dynamic values. "the delete button is specified by an trash icon not as a button but its an image". I have added the source code and java code which i have written  for this.

```js
    driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_btnAdd")).click();//add is working
          driver.navigate().refresh();
           
        //  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('#phContent_GridView1 tr td ))
          Object t = driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_txtRoleName"));
    //    driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_4")).click();
    //   assertTrue(closeAlertAndGetItsText().matches("^Are you sure you want to delete this Role[\\s\\S]$"));
       if(t!=null && ((String) t).contains("individual2"))
       {
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/a[2]/i")).click();
         System.out.println("Role is deleted");
       //}
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
      driver.navigate().refresh();
       }
       }
         catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

```html
<td>manager</td><td>manger in the projec</td><td>
                                            Level 2
                                        </td><td>
                                            YES
                                        </td><td>
                                            <a id="phContent_GridView1_LinkButton1_1" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl03$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
                                            <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this Role?&#39;);" id="phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_1" class="btn btn-inverse" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl03$lnkDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                        </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>indone</td><td>indone</td><td>
                                            Level 1
                                        </td><td>
                                            YES
                                        </td><td>
                                            <a id="phContent_GridView1_LinkButton1_2" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl04$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
                                            <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this Role?&#39;);" id="phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_2" class="btn btn-inverse" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl04$lnkDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                        </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>indtwo</td><td>indtwo</td><td>
                                            Level 1
                                        </td><td>
                                            YES
                                        </td><td>
                                            <a id="phContent_GridView1_LinkButton1_3" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl05$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
                                            <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this Role?&#39;);" id="phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_3" class="btn btn-inverse" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl05$lnkDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                        </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>individual2</td><td>individual2</td><td>
                                            Level 1
                                        </td><td>
                                            YES
                                        </td><td>
                                            <a id="phContent_GridView1_LinkButton1_4" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl06$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
                                            <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this Role?&#39;);" id="phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_4" class="btn btn-inverse" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$phContent$GridView1$ctl06$lnkDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                        </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you give me the specific HTML code for Delete button..And i can see that you are using absolute Xpath to detect Delete Button.

Comment: i think this was specific code..." id="phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_3"......but i dont want specific row and coloumn giving....as after me if some one adds few more roles my code will not work..

Comment: The code will work, because even if they add new "Delete button(s) in new rows", their id(s) will be different. But, in case you want to delete certain role, then you can use xpath for that. For e.g., if you want to delete the row having the role as "individual2", you can use this xpath **"//td[.='individual2'][1]/following-sibling::*//a[2]"** I will be modifying my below code accordingly. See if that works for you.

Comment: @Sravani: Image is not visible here. If you have added the image in **imgur**, please share the link here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/bLGim3k this is the link...

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from your HTML snippet is that **the ids are different for different table items.** So, you can use them directly to click on the delete button/image.

Below is the way to click on the 3rd delete button :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_3")).click();
```

**Note:-** Also, after that, you might be getting an alert box (as per the snippet), which you can handle by switching to it and accepting it.

---

Just replace your code like this and try:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_btnAdd")).click();//add is working 
    driver.navigate().refresh(); 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='individual2'][1]/following-sibling::*//a[2]/i")).click(); //For click on the delete button for the row having role as "individual 2" 

    //Probably an alert box comes up after you click on delete button, which you can handle like this:
    /*Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      alert.accept(); //For deleting
      alert.dismiss(); //For dismissing and not deleting
    */

    driver.navigate().refresh(); 
   } 
  } 
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
```

**SUGGESTION: 'Implicit waits', like you have used `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` are basically used at the beginning when you are starting a browser instance, i.e, after this: `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()`. It assigns a global timeout which means, each time the selenium tries to find certain element, it has to wait for a maximum of that time. But, if you want to override the time limit of certain element, we have 'Explicit waits' for that. This link will help you in understanding 'Implict and Explicit waits': http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp**

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"phContent_txtRoleName"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.07 seconds

Comment: Lose this lines of code: `Object t = driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_txtRoleName"));
    //    driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_GridView1_lnkDelete_4")).click(); 
    //   assertTrue(closeAlertAndGetItsText().matches("^Are you sure you want to delete this Role[\\s\\S]$")); 
       if(t!=null && ((String) t).contains("individual2"))
       {` and try please

Comment: as i am very new to selenium and java...please take patience in explaining me by writing code....thanks in advance

Comment: @Sravani: I have edited my code above, under the line **Just replace your code like this and try:**> Please check it out and let me know, if you have any concerns over it.

Comment: this was the error..FAILED: testManageroles
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'My-PC', ip: '192.168.2.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: @Sravani: **I have made a change in the xpath. Please use the code now, and let me know how it goes.** In case it doesn't work, please tell if the delete button visible on the webpage directly, or do you have to click/hover on some element, and then it becomes visible? Furthermore, if you can add an image of the delete button that will be helpful too. Since your reputation is not enough, you can't upload an image directly. Please consider uploading in sites like **[imgur](http://imgur.com/)** and adding the link here.

Comment: ,i have added image..please check it out

Answer (score 0):

@Sravani: Please try and let me know what happens

```
driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_btnAdd")).click();//add is working
driver.navigate().refresh();
//Get the Record
WebElement Record = driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_txtRoleName"));
if(Record.getAttribute("value").isEmpty())
{
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
               driver.navigate().refresh();

}
else 
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/a[2]/i")).click();
                  System.out.println("Role is deleted");

}
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"phContent_txtRoleName"}                                 -this was the error..

Comment: Remove the Catch exception and run the script. You will get the same error message . can you give me the complete error message from there?

Comment: ya....i got that doubt as well and removed and ran it...previously it use to run by saying nullpointer exception and test use to pass.but role has,t deleted.but now test itself is failing

Comment: OK we will break question in Simple. Can you tell me what is the current situation ? Does it deletes the record now? If yes, then what kind of Dynamic event is thrown after Delete Action?

Comment: no it is not deleting....i have tried record and play back for delete whether the delete icon is working or not...it is working...but through my webdriver its not deleting...

Comment: OK.. Now the only line which making it fail is "if(t!=null && ((String) t).contains("individual2"))" can you recheck again for the  string 'individual2' and try something other instead of  this.

Comment: i have added my grid view image..please have allok